# Do most things in Wix have to be done by hand?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, wix

I've been using Click Once for longer while now and it was easy to deploy applications to my customers. But lately I decided it's time to move on as there are things that I simply can't fix in `ClickOnce` deployment (like ngen Devexpress libraries).

So I would like to move to WiX but I was wondering if I really have to

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Component Id="Executable.exe" Guid="{C4DCEDD2-B4FF-4DFB-B7D6-2FA8B16D7740}">
    <File Id="Executable.exe" Source="C:\MySourceFiles\Executable.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="documentation.html" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <File Id="documentation.html" Source="C:\MySourceFiles\documentation.html" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>

  ... each dll goes here
  ... each xml goes here
</DirectoryRef>
```

Do I have to really go thru 70+ files and put one by one and generate GUID for it? Can't it autogenerate it from Directory or something and then eventually I could just fill it in? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "By Hand". Everything in VS Installer/InstallShield also you do by hand. Leave coding everything in this world is done by hand. You can rephrase your question to "Do things in Wix have to be done by coding only?"

Comment: What I mean is that ClickOnce takes all the referenced dll's and assumes that it has to be inside the package so you just choose "Include" and it's automatically included. With WiX it seems i will have to type in 140 lines one by one and if any reference changes in a project/is added I will have to modify it. Isn't there an easy way to generate a first project and then add some things like ngen/additional directory creations etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't you can use the harvest tool heat to generate wxs files. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm for more info. There are more features in the latest build of 3.6 that are not documented here so check the help for your version.

Comment: Nice. This is what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of external wix tools out there you could try, here are a few:

[WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/)

[IsWix](http://iswix.codeplex.com/)

You could also roll your own custom script to generate the XML you need.

Answer (score 2):

> *Do I have to really go thru 70+ files and put one by one and generate GUID for it?*

No, you can omit the GUID. From the [Component element documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_component.htm) for the `GUID` attribute:

> If omitted, the default value is '*' which indicates that the linker
>   should generate a stable guid. Generatable guids are supported only
>   for components with a single file as the component's keypath or no
>   files and a registry value as the keypath.

You can also omit the File `Id` and `Keypath` attributes. `Id` can be generated automatically from the `Source` filename. And `KeyPath` is redundant because if a component has just one file, then wix will automatically mark that file as the keypath.